# What is the meaning of "he kicked up his heels" in the song "Ship in the Sky" by Woody Guthrie?

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

From [a song by Woody Guthrie](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/10_of_Woody_Guthrie's_Songs/Ship_in_the_Sky):

> Well, a curly-headed girl with a bright shining smile
>   Heard the roar of a plane as it sailed through the sky
>   To her playmates she said, with a bright twinkling eye
>   My Daddy flies that ship in the sky
>
> My Daddy flies that ship in the sky
>   My Daddy flies that ship in the sky
>   My Mama's not afraid and neither am I
>   'Cause my Daddy flies that ship in the sky
>
> Then a button-nosed kid, as he **kicked up his heels**
>   He said, My Daddy works in the iron and the steel
>   My Dad builds the planes and they fly through the sky
>   And that's what keeps your daddy up there so high

The bolded phrase was very hard for me to imagine. What did the boy actually do?

I found this definition for "[kick up one's heels](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/kick-up-your-heels)":

> to do things that you enjoy:
>   After final exams we *kicked up our heels* and had a really good party.

This meaning clearly fails to fit the song.

I then googled for images. Is this "kicking up of heels" similar to this (as if dancing)?

[image]

Or to this:

[image]

Or he could have been "kicking up his heels" in any of the possible ways, and we should imagine it ourselves?

Comment: Can I just say? I love this question just for all its fun imagery especially the kid literally kicking up his heel :D.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Kick up one's heels* doesn't designate any specific motion—it evokes an image of dancing so exuberantly that both one's heels are frequently off the ground at once.

I imagine Guthrie chose this phrase more for the rhyme with *steel* than as a literal descriptor. Like the little girl's "bright twinkling eye", it just conveys the happiness and pride the boy takes in his father's work.

Comment: Ah, so the boy was dancing or making some dancing movements. Up until today, I thought that he only put one of the heels up and held it by the hand, and after awhile put another of the heels up and held it by the hand.  Bending one's leg and holding the heel behind his back, like children do sometimes (standing on one leg only). [like this](https://goo.gl/mYYWXu)

Comment: @CowperKettle [This](http://66.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_llxe01MBAR1qcs4zto1_1280.jpg) is probably closer to what the image evokes.

Comment: It could just imply that he was being contrary, for the fun of it.

Comment: I think that it's more figurative, than literal. Jumping for joy comes to mind as an equivalent expression.

Comment: @Vekzhivi Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Kick one's heels up

to act frisky; to be lively and have fun. (Somewhat literal when said of hoofed animals.) From thefreedictionary.com 
The boy isn't doing anything special, he is just lively.